# Solve ODE in Python with for loop

Tags: python, matlab, ode

I am trying to port some MATLAB code I wrote to solve an ODE to Python, without using an ODE solver.
The ODE is the following: [image] with x(0)=0.314465408805031, to be solved for 2 seconds:

My working MATLAB code is:

```matlab
%% SIMULATION PARAMETERS
tmin=0;
tmax=2;
N=1000;
dt=(tmax-tmin)/N;
t=tmin:dt:tmax;

global D
global R_ON
global R_OFF
global m_D
global p
D=10e-9;
R_ON=1e2;
R_OFF=16e3;
R_INIT=11e3;
m_D=1e-14;
p=1;
% normalise x0 in [0,1]
x0=(R_OFF-R_INIT)/(R_OFF-R_ON);

%% SIMULATION

% Evolve state variable
[t,x] = ode23t(@memristorODE, t, x0);

function dxdt = memristorODE(t,x)
    % CONSTANTS
    global D
    global R_ON
    global R_OFF
    global m_D

    % ODE
    dxdt = ((m_D*R_ON)/D^2) * I(t,x);
    fprintf('t %s I %s dx %s \n',t,I(t,x),dxdt)
end

% Input voltage
function v = V(t)
    v = sin(2*pi*t);
end

% Current
function i = I(t,x)
    global D
    global R_ON
    global R_OFF
    
    i = V(t)./(R_ON*x + R_OFF*(1-x));
end
```

which outputs:
[image]

I am trying to do the same by using a for loop in Python, by calculating the update to x as x(t+1)=x(t)+dx/dt:

```py
import numpy as np

def V( t ):
    return np.sin( 2 * np.multiply( np.pi, t ) )


def I( t, x ):
    return V( t ) / (np.multiply( R_ON, x ) + np.multiply( R_OFF, (np.subtract( 1, x )) ))


def v_D( t, x ):
    return ((m_D * R_ON) / np.power( D, 2 )) * I( t, x )


def F( x ):
    return (1 - (2 * x - 1) ^ (2 * 10))


tmin = 0
tmax = 2
N = 1000
dt = (tmax - tmin) / N
time = np.arange( 0, 2 + dt, dt )

D = 10e-9
R_ON = 1e2
R_OFF = 16e3
R_INIT = 11e3
m_D = 1e-14
x = [ (R_OFF - R_INIT) / (R_OFF - R_ON) ]
current = [ 0.0 ]

for t in time[ :-1 ]:
    current.append( I( t, x[ -1 ] ) )
    x.append( x[ -1 ] + v_D( t, x[ -1 ] ) )
    
    print( "t", '{:.6e}'.format( t ), "I", '{:.6e}'.format( I( t, x[ -1 ] ) ), "dx",
           '{:.6e}'.format( v_D( t, x[ -1 ] ) ) )
```

and this instead outputs:
[image]

I can't work out where I'm going wrong.  The only difference I see is that `ode23t` in MATLAB infers the dt step size while it's fixed in Python.  I also tried using the same time samples that MATLAB used by hardcoding them in, but the results do not change.

I have also tried using `odeint( v_D, (R_OFF - R_INIT) / (R_OFF - R_ON),time` to evolve x and the results are identical to the ones calculated with my `for` loop.

Comment: `x(t+1)=x(t)+dx/dt` should probably be `x(t+1)=x(t)+dx/dt * dt`, no?

Comment: And even then, it is only the first order Euler method, not the second order trapezoidal method. You should really use a higher-order method to get physically relevant results.

Comment: Good points!  Moving in the direction of the gradient by the timestep `dt` did the trick!  I'm getting a reasonably good approximation which could definitely be improved by some other method.
Among all the Runge-Kutta methods, how would one choose which one to apply?

Comment: A higher order RK method will give you a better solution at the expense of execution time and memory usage. You will be able to use a larger timestep without losing as much accuracy though, so do some tradeoff studies to see which works best for you.